# Dialog-based Win32 API program will not display window when a Richedit control is used

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, dialog, richedit

I've written a dialog-based Windows application that contains two edit controls and two button controls. ResEdit 1.5.9-x64 was used to create the dialog window and place/position the controls. The program compiles and runs perfectly and everything is working as intended.

However, as soon as I place a richedit control on the dialog window, the application compiles without error, but when I try to run it, nothing happens. The window no longer appears and the Windows Task Manager shows no running instance of the program. I've searched online and on stackoverflow for some help with this issue, but I haven't found anything.

At this point, all I have done is place the richedit control on the dialog. I am not trying to interface with it in any way within the program.

Can anyone help me out or point me in the right direction as to what step I am missing?

Comment: "It is necessary to call the LoadLibrary function to load Riched32.dll, Riched20.dll, or Msftedit.dll before the dialog is created." Quote taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298375%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jesse's comment solved the problem, however, I was unable to mark the question answered. So I am using the answer my own question link.

"It is necessary to call the LoadLibrary function to load Riched32.dll, Riched20.dll, or Msftedit.dll before the dialog is created." Quote taken from here. – Jesse 1